# Is that possible to insert porcupine text editor in a tkinter window of my app?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, text, editor

I need a restructured text editor integrated to my app in tkinter to generating manually typed reports. I've found porcupine and I can open it in external window with a button. Porcupine is written in tkinter, so, is that possible to open it in a frame of my own app? Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

best,

https://github.com/Akuli/porcupine

Comment: Why don't you try reading through the source code/documentation? I think [this](https://github.com/Akuli/porcupine) might be the source code. I don't think there are many people who know about `porcupine` and `tkinter` and are answering questions on StackOverflow. Also you can use `idlelib` if you find that easier as `idle` also uses `tkinter`

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I'm going to try your suggestion.

Comment: Btw I kind of spent the last 1 week making my own text editor that works with Java and C++ using `tkinter` and `idlelib` so I know it can be done (just takes a lot of work). Good luck with it. If you have more specific questions like "how do I add syntax highlighting" google them or ask me.

Comment: (just takes a lot of work)... Thats why I think about porcupine, it is written in python and tkinter. I assume that just changing the "parent frame" will do the work, Unfortunately I couldn't find the correct code line to do so. I hope the authors  Kawaritai and Akuli see this. Thank you again for your kind comment.

Comment: I looked at the source code again and here is what I found out: [this](https://github.com/Akuli/porcupine/blob/1ad0d5fa8d944ef66a0dbb7e0100da3a13aebfda/porcupine/_state.py#L37) is the window is created, [here](https://github.com/Akuli/porcupine/blob/1ad0d5fa8d944ef66a0dbb7e0100da3a13aebfda/porcupine/tabs.py#L495) is the definition of `FileTab` and [here](https://github.com/Akuli/porcupine/blob/1ad0d5fa8d944ef66a0dbb7e0100da3a13aebfda/porcupine/tabs.py#L275) is the definition of `Tab` which inherits from `tk.Frame`. Exactly what functionality do you want to use?

Comment: Hey,  thanks for your time.  I need to open porcupine in a tkinter window (integration),  edit  a report in rst inserting some variables from my app and generate a html of pdf.  I´ll visit the source code again.  Many thanks!!

Comment: Do you need the syntax highlighting/tab manager/menu/extensions functionality? There are a lot of functions that you might want to use. Also there seems to be a way to create extensions for porcupine. That might be easier in your case.

Comment: Dear Mr. "TheLizzard",

No, just a simple text editor. But porcupine author wrote me that porcupine is not intended to do what I want. Consequently, this weekend I searched for other options and I've found a possibility of edit reportlab text in a simple gui, producing a pdf:

https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/free-pdf-maker-app-with-python/

For reasons out of the scope of this text I didn't want to use reportlab only programmaticaly. But it with an tkinter gui it fits my needs.  

Thank you very much again for your goodwill and cooperation.